# Generic SQL to get max value given table and column names as varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

it is very easy to use the following SQL to get value for a specific primary key: ID from a specific table: myTale:

```
DECLARE @v_maxID bigint;
SELECT @v_maxID = MAX(ID) FROM myTable;
```

What I need is a generic SQL codes to get the max value for a key from a table, where both key and table are specified as varchar(max) types as parameters:

```
DECLARE @v_maxID bigint;
-- SELECT @v_maxID = MAX(@p_ID) FROM @p_Table;
```

I comment out the SELECT since it is not working. I tried to build a SQL string and I can EXEC it, but I cannot get the max value back to my local variable(@v_maxID). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE @max bigint, @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = N'SELECT @max = MAX(' + @p_ID + ') FROM ' + @p_Table

EXEC sp_executesql 
    @query = @sql, 
    @params = N'@max bigint OUTPUT', 
    @max = @max OUTPUT 

PRINT @max
```

Answer (score 5):

Users are choosers, but I consider this an ugly idea (for being overgeneralized). And unoptimizable. Just write the SQL.

Comment: Amen +1 but I get a cookie for the technically correct answer.

Comment: I raised this question since I needed this piece of codes in a larger SP, not just a SP for this job.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't you just want:

SELECT MAX(ID) FROM mytable

Answer (score 0):

Just build the query at the app level, thus the query running would be just like the one above. Doing in on sql will certainly open you for sql injection, since you have to use exec(). Also in either case, be careful with user input.

Comment: Note that BC's answer suffers the same as exec, it is sql injectable. If you control the input, go ahead.

Comment: One would hope table and column names aren't user input, but you're right about parameter safety.

Comment: yes, this is just a small section of codes I need in my larger SP and this one will be run by a scheduled job daily. I do have total control of the SP for internal use.

Answer (score 0):

As [BC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571364/q-generic-sql-to-get-max-value/571401#571401) states, you have to use sp_executesql with an OUTPUT parameter.

[How to specify output parameters when you use the sp_executesql stored procedure in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499)